# Form-horizontal pulls form-group to the right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="right-block-title col-xs-12">Change Password</div>
</div>
<form id="change-password-form" class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="oldpass" class="control-label col-xs-4">Old Password</label>
    <input id="oldpass" type="password" name="oldpass" class="col-xs-8"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="newpass" class="control-label col-xs-4">New Password</label>
    <input id="newpass" type="password" name="newpass" class="col-xs-8"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="confirmnew" class="control-label col-xs-4">Confirm Password</label>
    <input id="confirmnew" type="password" name="confirmnew" class="col-xs-8"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

And here's the result:
https://jsfiddle.net/bsdca8zc/7/

If your screen is big enough, you'll see that the form gets sucked to the right. I want to have it all aligned to the left (like the title).

I tried `pull-left`on the form-group elements, but it breaks the layout.
A negative `margin-left` on the `form-group` elements works, but it's not clean at all since it'll break  every time we change the labels (and I also don't think it's good for responsive reasons).

Answer (score -1):

The [horizontal form](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) is intended to show the labels inline for resolutions small and up. It shows the labels on top for xs. You would need to add the class form-control to your inputs for this behavior. It wasn't clear if that is what you were after or not.

If you are just wanting to align the labels here is an example. The col-sm-3 was replaced with col-xs-3 and text-right was added to right align the text.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="oldpass" class="control-label col-xs-3 text-right">Old Password</label>
    <input id="oldpass" type="password" name="oldpass" class="col-sm-6"/>
    <div class="indicator col-offset-3"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1heet5re/

Might need a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve to help more.